# Why a procedure cannot call another in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have 2 procedures (A,B) in Oracle 9i. In individual, they all work fine. But I cannot make a procedure C that calls A, which in turn calls B. I put a dbms_output.put_line before C calls A, before A calls B and one in B. Somehow, only the first put_line works. What are the possible reasons why this doesn't work? Thank you,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE C (num in number)
as
begin
    for r in (select col1 from Table1)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('Inside C');
        A(r.col1);
    end loop;
end;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE A (var1 IN varchar2)
AS
    v1 varchar2;
    cursor c1(c_var in varchar2) is 
       select col1 from table2 where col2=c_var;
BEGIN
    open c1(var1);
    loop
        fetch c1 into v1;
        exit when c1%notfound; 
        dbms_output.put_line ('Inside A');
        B(v1);
    end loop;
    close c1;
END;
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a dbms_output before you open the cursor in A to make sure you are even getting into the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviusly, cursor c1 is empty, so your condition (exit when c1%notfound) is true and loop is terminated before the dbms_output call.

If you want to print the line regardless of a empty cursor, change it's position, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE C (num in number)
as
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('Inside C');
    for r in (select col1 from Table1)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('Calling A');
        A(r.col1);
    end loop;
end;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE A (var1 IN varchar2)
AS
    v1 varchar2;
    cursor c1(c_var in varchar2) is
       select col1 from table2 where col2=c_var;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Inside A');
    open c1(var1);
    loop
        fetch c1 into v1;
        exit when c1%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line ('Calling B');
        B(v1);
    end loop;
    close c1;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an exception handler in C to detect if an exception is being thrown; something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE C (num in number) 
as 
begin 
    for r in (select col1 from Table1) 
    loop 
        dbms_output.put_line ('Inside C'); 
        A(r.col1); 
    end loop;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception caught in C : ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
    RAISE;
end;
```

Comment: If an exception is being raised it will propagate to the calling procedure, this WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL exception handler is unnecessary and bad practice. At the very least include a RAISE statement.